# Collisions between the player and enemy do not work anymore, Unity2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I am working on a space shooter game, and I was changing the size of the box collider. And when I turned the game on there weren't any collisions happening between the player and the enemy. Collisions between the enemy and laser still worked though. I can't put images in here, but Stack Overflow provided me with some links to the images. If I didn't provide you with enough of the code or anything else, please say so. I don't know what is going wrong and it's killing me. So can you see what is wrong?

ps: I'm very new to Unity

Player code:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Enemy")
        {
                Damage();
        }
    }
```

Enemy code

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Laser")
    {
    Destroy(other.gameObject);
    Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }

    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

[Player Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAbAk.png)

[Enemy Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxorO.png)

[Laser Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzYtr.png)

Answer (score 0):

[by "there weren't any collisions happening" do you mean

1. the method "OnTriggerEnter" is not called or
2. the methods in your if statements are not called?

For 1. Check if the player has a 2Dcollider attached.

For 2.: you use the "tag", did you tag the Player?

to fix some mistakes it is helpful to use:
Debug.Log("Enter message");
so you get a message in the console and can see if your Trigger even works or your if statement is the problem.]

---

edit: i looked up the inspectors and the player collider has the "IsTrigger" unchecked. not sure if that's the problem.

Comment: What is ment was that the method OnTriggerEnter2D wasn't called. But the player does have a 2Dcollider attached. So do you know what else could be the problem?

Comment: I just saw your edit. IsTrigger was unchecked bc I was experimenting. It is now checked again. But the problem is yet to be solved. So if you think of anything that might help do hesitate to say so.

Comment: maybe there is a problem because the Player has no Rigidbody2D but that's my only other idea

Comment: you can check that the Player's Rigidbody2D isKinematic so the physics don't get applied

Answer (score 0):

Your collider is unchecked in your player, also you need to check trigger in that collider.

Comment: Thx, i'm really new to Unity, so I make a lot of mistakes like this.

Comment: no problem, if both your colliders have triggers you use OnTriggerEnter, if both your colliders do not have triggers you use OnCollisionEnter, if this solved your problem feel free to accept the answer as correct :)